# Create new columns from String Columns that looks like JSON

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I got a table with 1 column which is a string type, but the inside looks like an json type.

The value looks like this

**'old_id'** column with value

```js
[{"name":"Entitas Penugasan","id":"6415","value":"HIJRA"},
 {"name":"Function","id":"10594","value":"People & Culture"},
 {"name":"Unit","id":"10595","value":"Organization Development"},
 {"name":"Tribe","id":"10602","value":"Shared Service"}
]
```

**'new_id'** column with value

```js
[{"name":"Entitas Penugasan","id":"6415","value":"AFS"},
 {"name":"Function","id":"10594","value":"Finance"},
 {"name":"Unit","id":"10595","value":"Finance Operations"},
 {"name":"Tribe","id":"10602","value":"Commercial"}
]
```

I need sql athena query to make columns old_name, old_id, old_value, new_name, new_id, new_value from those json columns

I've tried using

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(old_id, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 1) AS old_name,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(new_id, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 1) AS new_name,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(old_id, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 2) AS old_id,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(new_id, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 2) AS new_id,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(old_id, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 3) AS old_value,
REGEXP_EXTRACT(new_id, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 3) AS new_value
```

but it only generates 1 row, even though in the columns, it shows 4 'array'

The query should generate 4 rows, looks like below
[image]

| id | old_name | new_name | old_id | new_id | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Entitas Penugasan | Entitas Penugasan | 6415 | 6415 | HIJRA | AFS |
| A | Function | Function | 10594 | 10594 | People & Culture | Finance |
| A | Unit | Unit | 10595 | 10595 | Organization Development | Finance Operations |
| A | Tribe | Tribe | 10602 | 10602 | Shared Service | Commercial |

Is there any way to do it in SQL Athena?

---

Edit: I did a little progress with the query below

```
with raw_data as(
select id, user_id, old_custom_fields, new_custom_fields
    from my_table
    where 
    -- new_custom_fields <> '' and new_custom_fields<> 'None' and new_custom_fields is not null and
    id in (A)
),
splitted_data as (
    SELECT id, user_id,
    split(old_custom_fields, '},{') AS old_custom_field_id,
    split(new_custom_fields, '},{') AS new_custom_field_id
  FROM my_table
),
old_custom_field_id_unnest as (
SELECT
  *
 from splitted_data
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(old_custom_field_id) AS t (_old_custom_fields)
),
new_custom_field_id_unnest as (
SELECT
  *
 from splitted_data
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(new_custom_field_id) AS t (_new_custom_fields)
),
old_custom_field_cleaned as (
    select id, old_custom_field_id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(_old_custom_fields, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 1) AS old_name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(_old_custom_fields, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 2) AS old_id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(_old_custom_fields, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 3) AS old_value
    from old_custom_field_id_unnest
),
new_custom_field_cleaned as (
    select id, new_custom_field_id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(_new_custom_fields, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 1) AS new_name,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(_new_custom_fields, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 2) AS new_id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(_new_custom_fields, '"name":"(.*?)","id":"(.*?)","value":"(.*?)"', 3) AS new_value
    from new_custom_field_id_unnest
)
select oc.id, old_name, new_name,
    old_id,new_id,
    old_value,new_value
    from old_custom_field_cleaned oc 
    join new_custom_field_cleaned nc on oc.id = nc.id
```

But this leads to duplicated rows, now I have 16 rows due to the join, still needs help in removing the unneeded rows
[image]

Comment: will old_id and new_id always have the same number of elements?  Are we to assume you are comparing old_id[0] with new_id[0], old_id[1] with new_id[1]... and if so is there a field used to join those or is it just based on order of the data?

Comment: @TimMylott yes they always have same number of elements. And yes it's comparing old_id[0] with  new_id[0] and so on. They belong to same unique_id A, in this case. Right now I'm adding some logic in the join clause `on oc.unique_id = nc.unique_id and old_id = new_id`. But this clause is still needs testing as I'm still checking whether the old_id and new_id are always the same and only the old_value and new_value are changeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data does not just looks like JSON, the sample data is JSON, so process it as one. Depending on Presto/Trino version which is used the actual handling can be different but the common part would always be - parse JSON and cast it to `array` of some type and then unnest. For example you can use `ROW(name varchar, id varchar, value varchar)` (alternatives can be just `JSON` or `MAP(varchar, varchar)` or `MAP(varchar, JSON)` depending on the case):

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset(old_id, new_id) AS (
    VALUES
        ('[{"id":"6415","value":"HIJRA", "name":"Entitas Penugasan"},
             {"name":"Function","id":"10594","value":"People & Culture"},
             {"name":"Unit","id":"10595","value":"Organization Development"},
             {"name":"Tribe","id":"10602","value":"Shared Service"}
          ]',
          '[{"name":"Entitas Penugasan","id":"6415","value":"AFS"},
             {"name":"Function","id":"10594","value":"Finance"},
             {"name":"Unit","id":"10595","value":"Finance Operations"},
             {"name":"Tribe","id":"10602","value":"Commercial"}
            ]'
         )
)

-- query
SELECT t.*
FROM dataset,
unnest(cast(json_parse(old_id) as array(row(name varchar, id varchar, value varchar))),
    cast(json_parse(old_id) as array(row(name varchar, id varchar, value varchar)))) as t(old_name, old_id, old_value, new_name, new_id, new_value); -- maybe as t(old, new) depending on engine and select t.old.name as old_name, ...
```

Output:

| old_name | old_id | old_value | new_name | new_id | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Entitas Penugasan | 6415 | HIJRA | Entitas Penugasan | 6415 | HIJRA |
| Function | 10594 | People & Culture | Function | 10594 | People & Culture |
| Unit | 10595 | Organization Development | Unit | 10595 | Organization Development |
| Tribe | 10602 | Shared Service | Tribe | 10602 | Shared Service |

The above code comes from assumption that arrays have "same" data in correct order. Personally I would consider joining based on the id:

```
-- sample data
WITH dataset(old_id, new_id) AS (
   -- ..
),

-- query 
old_values as (
    SELECT t.*
    FROM dataset,
    unnest(cast(json_parse(old_id) as array(row(name varchar, id varchar, value varchar)))) as t(name, id, value)
),
new_values as (
    SELECT t.*
    FROM dataset,
    unnest(cast(json_parse(new_id) as array(row(name varchar, id varchar, value varchar)))) as t(name, id, value)
)

SELECT o.id,
       o.name old_name,
       o.value old_value,
       n.name new_name,
       n.value new_value
FROM old_values as o
full outer join new_values as n on o.id = n.id;
```

Output:

| id | old_name | old_value | new_name | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6415 | Entitas Penugasan | HIJRA | Entitas Penugasan | AFS |
| 10594 | Function | People & Culture | Function | Finance |
| 10595 | Unit | Organization Development | Unit | Finance Operations |
| 10602 | Tribe | Shared Service | Tribe | Commercial |